# IERC20 safeTransfer second token issue

Tags: solidity, transfer

I'm totally stacked! When a user interacts with contract token I want to send half of the amount of another specific  token to an specific address, I manage to do it this way but everytime the user interacts with the token the transfer is made from the token contract itself not from the user's contract...please help!

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract FinalToken {

 using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
 
 string public name; // Holds the name of the token
 string public symbol; // Holds the symbol of the token
 uint8 public decimals; // Holds the decimal places of the token
 uint256 public totalSupply; // Holds the total suppy of the token
 //address payable public owner; // Holds the owner of the token
 address public owner;
 uint256 public balance;

 /* This creates a mapping with all balances */
 mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
 /* This creates a mapping of accounts with allowances */
 mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;


constructor() {
        name = "FinalTestTokenDT02"; // Sets the name of the token, i.e Ether
        symbol = "FTTDT02"; // Sets the symbol of the token, i.e ETH
        decimals = 18; // Sets the number of decimal places
 uint256 _initialSupply = 10000000000 * 10 ** 18; // Holds an initial supply of coins

 /* Sets the owner of the token to whoever deployed it */
        owner = payable(msg.sender);

        balanceOf[owner] = _initialSupply; // Transfers all tokens to owner
        totalSupply = _initialSupply; // Sets the total supply of tokens
 
 }

 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
 
 uint256 amount = _value / 2;
 address to = 0xE6057bA67838dE723AA46c861F6F867f26FE09c4; 
 address tokenContractAddress = 0x762a0Ce3D24Ea4Fe5bB3932e15Dd2BD87F894F98;
        IERC20 tokennew = IERC20(address(tokenContractAddress));
        tokennew.safeTransfer(to, amount);
 
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the [safeTransfer()](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.7.0/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol#L22) function on `tokenContractAddress` is called by `FinalToken` (which is called by the user).

If you want to pull tokens from the user as a part of your function, the user needs to send 2 separate transactions.

1. First transaction to the `tokenContractAddress` contract directly, invoking its `approve()` function, passing `FinalToken` address as the spender.
2. And the second to your `FinalToken` contract as they are doing in your example already.

You also need to make a change to call `safeTransferFrom()` in your code - not `safeTransfer()` - passing the user address as the token sender.

```
IERC20 tokennew = IERC20(address(tokenContractAddress));
// user is the token sender, `to` is the recipient
tokennew.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, to, amount);
```